# Is is possible to specify default request/response format at a root level in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: swagger, openapi

In Swagger 2.0 there was a possibility to describe a default response and request content type on a root level:

```
produces:
  - application/json
```

The only way in OpenAPI 3.0 I have found is to describe it per request/response:

```
    responses:
     '200':
       content:
        application/json:
```

This is a bit cumbersome and repetitive if almost all of your request deal with only JSON data. So it was quite a nice feature to define a "default" behavior.

So I am really wondering if it is possible to have a default one with a possibility to override it if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, OpenAPI 3.0 does not have global media types. If you need this feature, consider [opening an issue](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues) in the OpenAPI Specification repository.